# GitKraken Unrecognized allowed types:8

Tags: tfs-2015, gitkraken

I'm using GitKraken 1.8.0 on windows 10 machine to connect TFS 2015 and when I try to do (Push, Pull, Fetch) I always get toast message error says

> Unrecognized allowed types:8

however, I can do these operations successfully using the CLI or Source Tree.

What is the cause of this issue!? and how to overcome that!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that TFS on a different domain and connecting my computer to this domain solved the problem and everything is working fine now.

The error message doesn't say much but I guess that **Unrecognized allowed types:8** error message is some sort of authentication error using the username in [domain\username] format isn't working in this case

Answer (score 1):

First disconnected and reconnected your TFS account and  try again. Also try to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).

Try to directly use Visual Studio with GIT when connecting TFS2015. If this also can work and since you can do the operations successfully using the CLI or Source Tree ,then the issue should related to GitKraken.

To use Gitkraken connect other remote Git repo such as the one hosted on GitHub. If you still got the same error. You may need to give a try with reinstall  GitKraken.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate GitKraken key, the step is Preference -> Authentication, choose General tab, and press Generate new Private/Public key "Generate" button.
2. Copy your gitkraken_rsa.pub key by press copy icon button. (SSH Public key item)
3. Paste your key into TFS server.
4. Copy your project SSH path from TFS to your Gitkraken Remote push/pull path and be careful there is no unnecessary ".git" word  behind your path, if there is, delete it.
5. Try to Git Fetch/Pull/Push by GitKraken!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old thread, but in case any of the mentioned solutions doesn't work for future readers, especially if you are NOT using any kind of integrations inside GitKraken, go to Credential Manager (Windows users) and under "Windows Credentials" -> "Generic Credentials" try to find your "git:" that is causing this issue and update the password to correct one for your git credentials.